# what is the url format to redirect page on cas authentification?

Tags: cas

how can i choose a redirect page on cas authentification?

This stay at the the same page:

```
https://mycas_server/cas/login
```

i would like to redirect the connected person to a "forced login page"

Comment: waht do you mean by  a "forced login page" , log again ?

Comment: the drupal cas module allows to configure which page that requires a cas authentification. basically i'd like to authenticate by cas then redirect to a specific page

Comment: just add a registred cas service (your url registered in cas services ) as parameter in login 
should be like `https://mycas_server/cas/login?service=http://yoururl`